# Missing Assembly Reference Trying to Compile .cs File With Mono

Tags: c#, mono, console-application, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to make a simple Console Application using Visual Studio for Mac (version 17.4). Current target framework is .NET 7.0 but I've toggled back and forth between .NET 6.0 with no luck. My goal is to set up something that can automatically run my application per a schedule I set. To that end I've come across using 'Mono' as a way to compile .cs files into .exe files and then run them from the Terminal. I can compile and run my application with no issues when I'm using Visual Studio for Mac. However when using (what I understand to be) the way to compile my .cs file into an executable using a bash script, I can't figure out how to resolve the series of *Are you missing an assembly reference?* errors I get. The script I'm using to compile my code is:

```
mcs /out:AmazonProductCheck.cs *.cs
```

Below is an image of the results I get after running the script above.[image: Terminal Results]

And here is an image of my using Directives in the .cs file I'm targeting in my bash script from above.
[image: Using Directives]

Any help is appreciated! I've scoured Stack Overflow for days now and while I've found the language 'Are you missing an assembly reference?' in quite a few posts I haven't been able to use the information in those posts to figure out my problem.

Things I've tried:
(1) Scouring Stack Overflow for searches like "Visual studio for mac mono Are you missing an assembly reference"
(2) Adding more 'using Directives' to the top of the code that is my entry point for this console app
(3) Copying some .dll files into the working directly where my .cs file lives
(4) Switching my target framework from 7.0 back to 6.0 within Visual Studio for Mac.

Expectation is that I can compile my .cs file into an executable and then run that executable with a bash script.

Comment: "To that end I've come across using 'Mono' as a way to compile .cs files into .exe files and then run them from the Terminal" is completely wrong. Go back to .NET 6/7 and start from there. Learn to use `dotnet build` to compile your project file at terminal, and forget about Mono things like mcs. That part of the story has ended, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/

Comment: Hey @LexLi! Thank you for taking the time to read my post. I'll check out dotnet build to see if I have some success there.